# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-explorer

I have installed Microsoft.azure.data nuget package in  visual studio but I m getting below error-
Program.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) below is my program code -

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data;
using System;
namespace LensDashboradOptimization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            //var clusterUrl = "https://mykusto.kusto.windows.net";

            // replace 'WithAadUserPromptAuthentication' with your preferred method of authentication
            //var kcsb = new Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder(clusterUrl); 


            //Console.WriteLine(kcsb);
            // Read the first row from reader -- it's 0'th column is the count of records in MyTable
            // Don't forget to dispose of reader when done.

            var client = Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider("https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true");
            var reader = client.ExecuteQuery("StormEvents | count");
            Console.WriteLine(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data nuget. then it compiles for me. It does give me authentication errors but not assembly reference errors.

```
using Kusto.Data.Net.Client;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider("https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples");
            var reader = client.ExecuteQuery("StormEvents | count");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, you'll have to read up on Kusto client authentication. I hope you got the assemblies loaded. Please mark the post answered if it did your question